# How to enter a password automatically when updating SQL data in an Excel file using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, password-protection

I have several Excel files which I want to update automatically using a PowerShell script. The data in these files is coming from a SQL Server database which is protected by a password.

I have no problem opening the file and then telling it to update all connections, but I have no idea how to enter the password for the SQL Server connection.

To be precise: the password needs to be entered 5 times because there are 5 connected SQL Server views.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do so that PowerShell outputs the password into the prompt?

Comment: Are you not able to use a trusted connection?

Comment: No, that is not possible. If so, I would have no Problem ;-)

Comment: Are you wanting the script to be completely autonomous, or will someone be starting it (i.e. can an initial prompt be provided for the password)?

Comment: Can you share the code or the instruction you are using that triggers the password request ?
I got in the past the need to change the connection password stored and I was able to do by using VBA to manipulate the
Connection properties of ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Database1433").OLEDBConnection
then use a ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Database1433").Refresh 
but cannot be sure if it is appliable to your case without seeing what you are exactly using to open the excel.